# How to fix "NameError: name method-name is not defined"?

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I'm having trouble with the following Python code:

```
class Methods:

    def method1(n):
        #method1 code

    def method2(N):
        #some method2 code
            for number in method1(1):
                #more method2 code

def main():
    m = Methods
    for number in m.method2(4):
            #conditional code goes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this code, I get

> NameError: name 'method1' is not defined.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You need to use `self.method1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add self. in front of it:

```
self.method1(1)
```

Also change your method signitures to:

```
def method1(self, n):
```

and

```
def method2(self, n):
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works!

Comment: @maestro777, enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like following:

```
class Methods:

    def method1(self,n):
        #method1 code

    def method2(self,N):
        #some method2 code
        for number in self.method1(1):
            #more method2 code

def main():
    m = Methods()
    for number in m.method2(4):
        #conditional code goes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1. Add a self parameter to every methods inside of your class
2. To call a method inside of your class use self.methodName(parameters)
3. To make instance of your class you should write class name with paranteses for ex: m = Methods()